# ERPTable columns being truncated

Tags: c#, linq, sap-erp, erpconnect

I've generated some proxy ERPTables to query SAP tables. The columns are generated as type string. Since ERPConnect Linq doesn't seem to support join, like or basically any query in the where clause more complex than equality comparisons, I had to split the join in several individual queries and do the joins in C#. The problem is that some of the GUID key columns are coming truncated to 16 characters.

I've been trying to investigate this but the ERPTable doesn't seem to have any adjustable parameter for this. I highly suspect that is some shanenigan in the SAP side but I don't know what checks to do in order to constrain the source of the problem.

Has anyone experienced this problem with ERPConnect?

Comment: +1 for the question, i feel your pain as I have to deal with this sort of stuff all the time due to the nature of the business and the extreme use of SAP to run our business.

Comment: Could you please list the tables and the exact type (data element) of the GUID fields?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the custom function "Z_XTRACT_IS_TABLE" like described in the Help in the lower part (Table Access Restrictions):

http://help.theobald-software.com/ERPConnect-EN/default.aspx?pageid=reading-sap-tables-directly-with-readtable

If you are using Linq you can find it here:

http://help.theobald-software.com/ERPConnect-EN/default.aspx?pageid=linq-to-sap-table-access-restrictions

This is an SAP Restriction, and when using the default function module, only the first 16 chars are sent.

Best Regards,

Ali